# Bibliography style with elsarticle

Tags: elsarticle

I have trouble getting the form of citations I need. Once I cite I want to see authors' names and not numbers. The unconventional thing is that I have to use the documentclass elsarticle (This is editor's request), which always produce numbers. Here is it what I have

```
\documentclass{elsarticle}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,linkcolor=black, citecolor=blue, urlcolor=blue]{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{references}

\end{document}
```

Can someone help me on this?

Here's an expanded MWE.

```
\documentclass{elsarticle}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath, mathtools}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,linkcolor=black, citecolor=blue, urlcolor=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage{changes}
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}



\begin{document}

\section{The Model}

The main environment modifies that of \cite{Diamond1965}, into two main dimensions

\newpage

\bibliographystyle{elsarticle-harv}
\bibliography{references}



\end{document}
```

Comment: Is this to be sent to a journal or is this intended to be a personal copy?

Comment: The numeric-style citations are *not* generated by the `elarticle` document class: they are generated by your choice of the `plainnat` bibliography style.

Comment: It is for publication, I experimented with elsartic-harv and chicago, but still get number citation style.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You should specify `authoryear` in the class options.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{Diamond1965,
 author={J. A. L. Diamond},
 title={Some Like It Hot},
 journal={J. High Level Cinema},
 year={1965},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[authoryear]{elsarticle}

\usepackage[colorlinks=true,linkcolor=black, citecolor=blue, urlcolor=blue]{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\section{The Model}

The main environment modifies that of \cite{Diamond1965}, into two main dimensions

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

The `filecontents*` environment is just to make the example selfcontained, you don't need it; change the `\bibliography` line to have the name of your `.bib` file.

Yes, I know that “Some Like It Hot” wasn't shot in 1965. `;-)`

[image]

Adding the `authoryear` to `natbib` is not a solution, because the `elsarticle` class already loads it, so having

```
\usepackage[authoryear]{natbib}
```

in the preamble will only cause an error about conflicting options.

Comment: It works. Much appreciated. I was using the authoryear option into natbib package.

Answer (score 10):

Since you're using the `elsarticle` document class, you may want to use the `elsarticle-harv` instead of the `plainnat` bibliography style. As its name suggests, `elsarticle-harv.bst` gives you authoryear-style citations -- aka harvard-style citations -- and references that are formatted according to the guidelines of most Elsevier-run journals that require authoryear-style citations.

Moreover, in order to activate full authoryear style (with years rather than numbers), `authoryear` should be specified as a documentclass option:

```
\documentclass[authoryear]{elsarticle}
```

(This information added after the OP posted an MWE.)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I changed to elsarticle-harv, but for some mysterious reason to me I still get the number style citation.

Comment: @user17880 - After changing the argument of the `\bibliographystyle` instruction, did you run LaTeX, BibTeX, and LaTeX twice more? Also, do try adding the option `authoryear` when loading the `natbib` package, i.e., typing `\usepackage[authoryear]{natbib}` (and, of course, rerun LaTeX, BibTeX, and LaTeX twice more).

Comment: I did it now, but it does nothing. I also, delete the whole files that latex is producing after compiling but again nothing happens. I only get authors names if I changed the document class to, for example, article.

Answer (score 8):

if you are using the elsevier reference style (which contains all the packages itself) you can pose bibliography options like this:

```
\bibliographystyle{elsarticle-harv}\biboptions{authoryear}
```