# create bibliography in the order as the input in bibtex using elsarticle

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, sorting, elsarticle

I am trying to put my article in the revised version using "elsarticle.cls", format "number" and bibtex as required by the journal.

My question is that the bibliography is created in the order of citation in my article, but I want to create a bibliography in the order as I input in bibtex ( where I sort the reference according to the alphabeta of the last name of authors in bibtex) not depending on the order of citation.

Any help is appreciated!

Here is the relevant code I used in the article.

---

```
\documentclass[preprint]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{lineno,hyperref}
\begin{document}
\section{1}
\bibliography{mybibfile}
\bibliographystyle{elsarticle-num}
\end{document}
```

---

Answer (score 1):

You can follow the example here:
[Bibliography style with elsarticle](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/167426/bibliography-style-with-elsarticle).
Specifically, you need to specify `authoryear` in the documentclass options. `\bibliographystyle` needs to be `elsarticle-harv`.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{Diamond1965,
 author={J. A. L. Diamond},
 title={Some Like It Hot},
 journal={J. High Level Cinema},
 year={1965},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[authoryear]{elsarticle}

\usepackage[colorlinks=true,linkcolor=black, citecolor=blue, urlcolor=blue]{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\section{The Model}

The main environment modifies that of \cite{Diamond1965}, into two main dimensions

\bibliographystyle{elsarticle-harv}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks! is it possible to fix this problem using \bibliographystyle{elsarticle-num}? it seems the journal suggests to use this format.

Comment: And I want to see numbers but not authors' names once I cite the reference...

Comment: @Adam. All the options are here: [https://www.elsevier.com/authors/author-schemas/latex-instructions]. Have a look in manifest.txt to determine which template matches your target journal. Each template specifies the necessary `\bibliographystyle` file. The templates also provide instructions on how to specify the citations in the body of the text.

Comment: @Adam Can you please confirm the journal really demands this style?