# Editorial Manager latex compiler not building correctly

Tags: natbib, compiling

I am submitting a manuscript for submission to a springer journal through editorial manager, and all I get back is pages of code when I attempt to compile. I am not sure what the problem is. The editorial manager lists XeLatex as an available compiler, which is the compiler I am using. I have all Figures, bibliography (.bib) and style files in the same directory as the manuscript.tex file (no subfolders). I get a ton of these errors popping up:

```
Package natbib Warning: Citation `eckbreth1996laser' on page 9 undefined
on inp
ut line 483.
```

If anyone has a solution please let me know! See more code attached below (first 4 pages, will post more if needed. It wouldn't let me attach any more).

thanks

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.19 (TeX Live 2018/W32TeX)
(preloaded format=pdflatex 2018.7.12) 13 MAY 2019 14:23
entering extended mode
restricted \write18 enabled.
%&-line parsing enabled.
**manuscript.tex
(./manuscript.tex
LaTeX2e <2018-04-01> patch level 5
LaTeX Warning: File `example.eps' already exists on the system.
Not generating it from this source.
(c:/TeXLive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fix-cm.sty
Package: fix-cm 2015/01/14 v1.1t fixes to LaTeX
(c:/TeXLive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1enc.def
File: ts1enc.def 2001/06/05 v3.0e (jk/car/fm) Standard LaTeX file
Now handling font encoding TS1 ...
... processing UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding TS1
(c:/TeXLive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1enc.dfu
File: ts1enc.dfu 2018/04/05 v1.2c UTF-8 support for inputenc
defining Unicode char U+00A2 (decimal 162)
defining Unicode char U+00A3 (decimal 163)
defining Unicode char U+00A4 (decimal 164)
defining Unicode char U+00A5 (decimal 165)
defining Unicode char U+00A6 (decimal 166)
defining Unicode char U+00A7 (decimal 167)
defining Unicode char U+00A8 (decimal 168)
defining Unicode char U+00A9 (decimal 169)
defining Unicode char U+00AA (decimal 170)
defining Unicode char U+00AC (decimal 172)
defining Unicode char U+00AE (decimal 174)
defining Unicode char U+00AF (decimal 175)
defining Unicode char U+00B0 (decimal 176)
defining Unicode char U+00B1 (decimal 177)
defining Unicode char U+00B2 (decimal 178)
defining Unicode char U+00B3 (decimal 179)
defining Unicode char U+00B4 (decimal 180)
defining Unicode char U+00B5 (decimal 181)
defining Unicode char U+00B6 (decimal 182)
defining Unicode char U+00B7 (decimal 183)
defining Unicode char U+00B9 (decimal 185)
defining Unicode char U+00BA (decimal 186)
defining Unicode char U+00BC (decimal 188)
defining Unicode char U+00BD (decimal 189)
defining Unicode char U+00BE (decimal 190)
defining Unicode char U+00D7 (decimal 215)
defining Unicode char U+00F7 (decimal 247)
defining Unicode char U+0192 (decimal 402)
defining Unicode char U+02C7 (decimal 711)
defining Unicode char U+02D8 (decimal 728)
defining Unicode char U+02DD (decimal 733)
defining Unicode char U+0E3F (decimal 3647)
defining Unicode char U+2016 (decimal 8214)
defining Unicode char U+2020 (decimal 8224)
defining Unicode char U+2021 (decimal 8225)
defining Unicode char U+2022 (decimal 8226)
defining Unicode char U+2030 (decimal 8240)
defining Unicode char U+2031 (decimal 8241)
defining Unicode char U+203B (decimal 8251)
defining Unicode char U+203D (decimal 8253)
defining Unicode char U+2044 (decimal 8260)
defining Unicode char U+204E (decimal 8270)
defining Unicode char U+2052 (decimal 8274)
defining Unicode char U+20A1 (decimal 8353)
defining Unicode char U+20A4 (decimal 8356)
defining Unicode char U+20A6 (decimal 8358)
defining Unicode char U+20A9 (decimal 8361)
defining Unicode char U+20AB (decimal 8363)
defining Unicode char U+20AC (decimal 8364)
defining Unicode char U+20B1 (decimal 8369)
defining Unicode char U+2103 (decimal 8451)
defining Unicode char U+2116 (decimal 8470)
defining Unicode char U+2117 (decimal 8471)
defining Unicode char U+211E (decimal 8478)
defining Unicode char U+2120 (decimal 8480)
defining Unicode char U+2122 (decimal 8482)
defining Unicode char U+2126 (decimal 8486)
defining Unicode char U+2127 (decimal 8487)
defining Unicode char U+212E (decimal 8494)
defining Unicode char U+2190 (decimal 8592)
defining Unicode char U+2191 (decimal 8593)
defining Unicode char U+2192 (decimal 8594)
defining Unicode char U+2193 (decimal 8595)
defining Unicode char U+2329 (decimal 9001)
defining Unicode char U+232A (decimal 9002)
defining Unicode char U+2422 (decimal 9250)
defining Unicode char U+25E6 (decimal 9702)
defining Unicode char U+25EF (decimal 9711)
defining Unicode char U+266A (decimal 9834)
defining Unicode char U+FEFF (decimal 65279)
))) (./svjour3.cls
Document Class: svjour3 2007/05/08 v3.2
LaTeX document class for Springer journals
(c:/TeXLive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fleqn.clo
File: fleqn.clo 2016/12/29 v1.2a Standard LaTeX option (flush left
equations)
\mathindent=\dimen102
Applying: [2015/01/01] Make \[ robust on input line 50.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \[ on input line 51.
Already applied: [0000/00/00] Make \[ robust on input line 62.
Applying: [2015/01/01] Make \] robust on input line 74.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \] on input line 75.
Already applied: [0000/00/00] Make \] robust on input line 83.
)
Class Springer-SVJour3 Info: extra/valid Springer sub-package (-> *.clo)
(Springer-SVJour3) not found in option list of \documentclass
(Springer-SVJour3) - autoactivating "global" style.
(./svglov3.clo
File: svglov3.clo 2009/12/18 v3.2 style option for standardised journals
SVJour Class option: svglov3.clo for standardised journals
)
LaTeX Font Info: Redeclaring math symbol \Gamma on input line 147.
LaTeX Font Info: Redeclaring math symbol \Delta on input line 148.
LaTeX Font Info: Redeclaring math symbol \Theta on input line 149.
LaTeX Font Info: Redeclaring math symbol \Lambda on input line 150.
LaTeX Font Info: Redeclaring math symbol \Xi on input line 151.
LaTeX Font Info: Redeclaring math symbol \Pi on input line 152.
LaTeX Font Info: Redeclaring math symbol \Sigma on input line 153.
LaTeX Font Info: Redeclaring math symbol \Upsilon on input line 154.
LaTeX Font Info: Redeclaring math symbol \Phi on input line 155.
LaTeX Font Info: Redeclaring math symbol \Psi on input line 156.
LaTeX Font Info: Redeclaring math symbol \Omega on input line 157.
\logodepth=\dimen103
\headerboxheight=\dimen104
\betweenumberspace=\dimen105
\aftertext=\dimen106
\headlineindent=\dimen107
\c@inst=\count80
\c@auth=\count81
\instindent=\dimen108
\authrun=\box26
\authorrunning=\toks14
\titrun=\box27
\titlerunning=\toks15
\combirun=\box28
\c@lastpage=\count82
\rubricwidth=\dimen109
\c@section=\count83
\c@subsection=\count84
\c@subsubsection=\count85
\c@paragraph=\count86
\c@subparagraph=\count87
\spthmsep=\dimen110
\c@theorem=\count88
\c@case=\count89
\c@conjecture=\count90
\c@corollary=\count91
\c@definition=\count92
\c@example=\count93
\c@exercise=\count94
\c@lemma=\count95
\c@note=\count96
\c@problem=\count97
\c@property=\count98
\c@proposition=\count99
\c@question=\count100
\c@solution=\count101
\c@remark=\count102
\c@figure=\count103
\c@table=\count104
\abovecaptionskip=\skip41
\belowcaptionskip=\skip42
\figcapgap=\dimen111
\tabcapgap=\dimen112
\figgap=\dimen113
\bibindent=\dimen114
\@tempcntc=\count105
) (c:/TeXLive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz.sty
(c:/TeXLive/
2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/basiclayer/pgf.sty (c:/TeXLive/2018/texmfdist/
te
x/latex/pgf/utilities/pgfrcs.sty (c:/TeXLive/2018/texmfdist/
tex/generic/pgf/ut
ilities/pgfutil-common.tex
\pgfutil@everybye=\toks16
\pgfutil@tempdima=\dimen115
\pgfutil@tempdimb=\dimen116
(c:/TeXLive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-commonlists.
tex)
) (c:/TeXLive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-latex.def
\pgfutil@abb=\box29
(c:/TeXLive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ms/everyshi.sty
Package: everyshi 2001/05/15 v3.00 EveryShipout Package (MS)
)) (c:/TeXLive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfrcs.code.tex
Package: pgfrcs 2015/08/07 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.31)
))
Package: pgf 2015/08/07 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.15)
(c:/TeXLive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcore.sty
(c:/TeXLive/20
18/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
Package: graphicx 2017/06/01 v1.1a Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
(c:/TeXLive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty
Package: keyval 2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks17
) (c:/TeXLive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
Package: graphics 2017/06/25 v1.2c Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
(c:/TeXLive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty
Package: trig 2016/01/03 v1.10 sin cos tan (DPC)
) (c:/TeXLive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/graphics.cfg
File: graphics.cfg 2016/06/04 v1.11 sample graphics configuration
)
Package graphics Info: Driver file: pdftex.def on input line 99.
(c:/TeXLive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/pdftex.def
File: pdftex.def 2018/01/08 v1.0l Graphics/color driver for pdftex
))
\Gin@req@height=\dimen117
\Gin@req@width=\dimen118
) (c:/TeXLive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys.sty
(c:/TeXLive/
2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys.code.tex
Package: pgfsys 2014/07/09 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.48)
(c:/TeXLive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.code.tex
\pgfkeys@pathtoks=\toks18
\pgfkeys@temptoks=\toks19
(c:/TeXLive/2018/texmfdist/
tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeysfiltered.code.tex
```

Comment: Some journals don't run bibtex. You need to include your `*.bst` file into the `*.tex` source before uploading.

Comment: @OlegLobachev -- Don't you mean "include your `*.bbl` file into the `*.tex` source'?

Comment: @barbarabeeton Ooops, yeah. The one with final citations in it.

Comment: I used biblatex (have a .bib file). So I need to list my references at the bottom of the 
main .tex file?

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar problem for an Elsevier article (based on `elsarticle-template-num.tex`). What worked for me was to embed the bib data into the `.tex` file, as in [Bibliography style with elsarticle](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/167426/bibliography-style-with-elsarticle).

Add the content of your .bib file AFTER the document class, for example before your preamble). Below, just one reference was added, but you can have as many as needed.

Also, make sure you use the same file name in the filecontents enviroment and in the command of bibliography, in the example below 'fileName.bib' and 'fileName', were used respectively.

Example:

```
\documentclass[preprint,12pt]{elsarticle}

\begin{filecontents*}{fileName.bib}

@article{gosling_mice_2001,
    title = {From mice to men: what can we learn about personality from animal research?},
    volume = {127},
    issn = {1939-1455},
    doi = {10.1037/0033-2909.127.1.45},
    number = {1},
    journal = {Psychol Bull},
    author = {Gosling, Samuel D},
    year = {2001},
    keywords = {animal personalities, cross-species comparisons},
    pages = {45--86},
    ,
}

\end{filecontents*}

<YOUR PREAMPLE>

\begin{document}

<YOUR CONTENT>

\bibliographystyle{elsarticle-num} 
\bibliography{fileName}

\end{document}
```